# How to specify class or function type in docstring for PyCharm parser

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I use a lot the Pycharm docstring type parser in order to specify the types of the methods parameters and return, the attributes or the instance variable. If it works nearly all the time, I have a little issue about telling PyCharm I am giving a function or a class as parameter/attribute/...

Here is a short example :

```
class Bar:

    def __init__(self, bar):
        """
        :type bar: str
        """
        print bar

class Foo:
    """
    :type my_class: Bar.__class__
    """

    def __init__(self, cinstance=Bar):
        """
        :type cinstance: Bar.__class__
        """
        self.my_class = cinstance

    def run(self):
        # it should print an unexpected type warning, but it doesn't.
        self.my_class(2)
```

If I just put `Bar` instead of `Bar.__class__`, of course PyCharm tell me that `Bar` cannot be call. So how to tell him that I'm giving him the class ?

Note that with the `@classmethod` decorator, PyCharm has no issue to understand we are speaking about the class and not the instance.

Here are my attempts :

[image: Attempt with <code>Bar.__name__</code>]

[image: Attempt with <code>Bar.__class__</code>]

[image: Attempt with <code>Bar</code>]

Comment: A JetBrain ticket is open : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/66648

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PyCharm support told me the following :

> As PyCharm developer said: You cannot distinguish classes and instances in type hints. The name of a class in a type hint means that an instance of that class is expected. If your function accepts the class itself, your options are either not to use type hints at all or use the 'type' as a class name. Anyway, there won't be any useful code completion in these cases. See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11615.

The only way to specificate an argument is a class is to use `:type arg: type`, but the completion won't work well. There is no other way currently.

Comment: In such cases I usually use type with parameter ``:type arg: type[SomeClass]``. It doesn't provide syntax help either but it's valid type hinting syntax and it's more specific than just ``type``.

Comment: @warownia1 It appears type hinting for `:type arg: type[SomeClass]` works properly in PyCharm 2017.3.4. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: You can get code completion for the variable by inserting an ```assert issubclass(cls, SomeClass)``` statement above the first usage of that variable

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify that a parameter is of type `SomeClass`, it should be declared as such:

```
@type (param): SomeClass
```

Specified properly, you should get something like this:

[image: part 1]

If you *don't* specify the type of the parameter properly:

[image: part 2]

At this point, I figured I would dig a little deeper to see if I could find anything interesting. If you go to the declaration of an object's `.__class__`, you'll be directed here (in `builtins.py`):

[image: part 3]

Perhaps `__class__` was set to `None`? Even if it is by default but then updated when the class gets instantiated (which would be my guess as to what happens), this might be what PyCharm infers `__class__` resolves to. All of this is just speculation on my end and may as well be incorrect, but... Just for the heck of it, what behavior can we see if we set a parameter's type to `None`, then?

[image: part 4]

Looks like the same thing that happened when we set the type to `SomeClass.__fake__` (and I tested it with `SomeClass.__class__`, and the same thing happens there too.)

So I suppose the question at hand is, why can't you use `@type cinstance: Bar`?

Comment: FYI, thanks to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22552647/4009370) for PyCharm-supported documentation style

Comment: I read your answer but i'm not sure you got the issue : I'm looking for a way to pass a class as attribute, and not an instance as attribute. I knew that for an instance, `@param toto: Bar` is alright, but how to tell "I want as parameter a non instantiated class equals or inherited from Bar" ?

Comment: @FunkySayu I see. Did you try `.__name__` or just `class`? Also, if you happen to get `class` working, I'm not sure it will do what you want it to do, because a `class` object won't have any knowledge of which class it actually resolves to (right?)

Comment: (I added some screen shots in order to have a better explanation). I tryied with name also, but it is still not working. About the second question you asked (which is interesting), my logic was if you have an inherited class of Bar, it would generally overwrite or let as defined the methods of Bar. But as you said, it looks like `__class__` is *not* defined for old-style classes, and is defined as `type` for new-style classes. I'm not sure there is a way to do that.

Comment: I opened a JetBrain support how-to ticket about my issue. If I have some informations, I will dispatch them here.

Comment: Cool. Sorry I couldn't answer your question properly, but cheers for being so thorough!

Answer (score 1):

For functions, specifying using `callable` works with PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from typing import Type

def __init__(self, klass: Type[Bar]):
    pass
```